# Error when delegating initialization in swift struct

Tags: swift

I am trying to use another initalizer when some edge case happens during initialization, but I realized that once I delegate initialization to another initalizer, I can't treat that initializer like I would a normal one, instead I have to delegate initialization in all code branches.

(real use case is to initialize a struct containing email and name from a `ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential` But because this object only returns the email and name the first time the user signs up with Apple, I have to check if it contains it, if no then an initalizer is called, that can create one by loading it from `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore`. I ended up solving this by creating a function returning this struct instead of an init function)

The errors I get are

> 'self' used before 'self.init' call or assignment to 'self'

> 'self.init' isn't called on all paths before returning from initializer

These come up when I try to use a different initializer in a guard statement's else closure. Here is a simplified example:

```
struct Test {
    var name : String
    var age : Int
    
    init(name : String) {
        self.name = name
        self.age = -1
    }
    
    init(name : String, age : Int?) {
        guard let age = age else {
            self.init(name: name)
            return
        }
        
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }
}
```

Another solution I found is to create an init that can be called after the guard statement, in this case:

```
init(name: String, age : Int) {
     self.name = name
     self.age = age
}
```

and then use this init instead of assigning values directly.

**My question is**: why is this the case, and where is this behaviour mentioned or explained? The only documentation I found about this was the swift docs here:
https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html#ID215

Comment: Off topic but I try to avoid using return in an init unless its an failable initializer

Comment: It is necessary in this case because the guard statement's else closure needs to end in a return statement or needs to throw something. The compiler also complains otherwise

Comment: Yes maybe I was a bit unclear but it was implied that I didn’t like to use guard in this way for the same reason

Comment: Also what is the use case for the second init, I prefer not to add additional init methods until I have a real use case. In this scenario making age optional seems redundant considering you already have an init that doesn’t take age as an argument. And lastly I would consider the base init (that is called by others) should take all properties as parameters. Sorry for the slightly off topic rant.

Comment: The example just showcases the issue, I understand that this way design flaws can't really be corrected, but I was more curious about the way I should have known this, or where I could have read about this. Because to me it seems that the only documentation on this is the official one which isn't very detailed.

I edited the question now to better reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about other languages but in Swift you have to first initialise existing initialiser before initialising extra property/properties.

```
import UIKit

struct Test {
    var name : String
    var age : Int
    
    init(name : String) {
        self.name = name
        self.age = -1
    }
    
    init(name : String, age : Int?) {
        
        self.init(name: name)
        
        if let age = age {
            self.name = name
            self.age = age
        }
        
        
        
    }
}

let x = Test(name: "x", age: nil)
let y = Test(name: "y", age: 18)
let z = Test(name: "z")
```

Comment: OP is not asking how to do it but why it doesn’t work the way it is implemented in the question.

Comment: I know what he asked, I just told him, that's just the way it is: for example if someone asks me, why does Earthquakes occur? I will reply, movement of tectonic plates causes the Earthquake, then they will ask why does the plates move, my reply would be same as in this question, "that's just the way it is". It's basic rule.